# OpenCV VideoCapture only updates after 5 read()s

Tags: python, opencv

I have a very strange error that has been plaguing my research for a few years now. I'm using OpenCV2 with Python to read image data from a webcam. However, the image is lagged by 5 frames. In other words, each call to read() is 5 frame behind real-time.

One bandage fix I have been using is to grab() 4 frames and then read the 5th every time I need an updated image, but that absolutely murders my performance.

Here's the code that I am using to display the images from the webcam

```
    frame = self.getGoodFrame()

    if self.DEBUG:
        window = cv2.namedWindow("Angles")
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)

    ... Reseach specific code I shouldn't be giving out here ...
    ... It finds the center of a few bright colors in an image

    if self.DEBUG:
        debugImage = numpy.zeros((self.CAMERA_HEIGHT, self.CAMERA_WIDTH), numpy.uint8) #blank image

       ... Then we draw some stuff to the image to be displayed ...

        cv2.imshow("Angles", debugImage)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        raw_input()
```

and getGoodFrame()

```
def getGoodFrame(self):
    MIN_READS_FOR_GOOD_FRAME = 4

    for i in xrange(MIN_READS_FOR_GOOD_FRAME):
        successful_read = self.capture.grab() 

    successful_read, frame = self.capture.read()

    if not successful_read:
        print "Unable to read from webcam, exiting."

    return frame
```

You'll notice that I have a raw_input() call. That makes it so I can see how many reads need to happen by pressing enter a few times in console. This shows that there is exactly 5 frames of lag.

I don't think it's a hardware issue, I've had this happen with multiple webcams and multiple USB cords. I haven't tried reproducing the error on another machine though.

Comment: Can you tell us how you know there is a 5 frame 'lag'?

Comment: I noticed that there was a visual lag then I tested it out by have a loop that would read() a frame, display it to a window then wait for raw input. You can see this minus the while loop in my first code snippet. I found that I had to hit enter to move back to the top of the loop exactly 5 times before the image in the window matched up to what the camera saw at the start of my calling the loop.

Comment: I should also add that it's not related to the displaying of the image. I tried the same thing but instead of showing the image, I just spit out some data about the image and the same 5 frame lag was in place.

Comment: What is your definition of real time?  Web cams deliver frames at 30 fps but the jitter between frames most likely does not qualify for real time.  If it takes 5 frames for the image to actually change then that is something different.

Comment: Yeah, it takes 5 frames for the image to update but only when using OpenCV's VideoCapture to read() frames. In Cheese, it's totally fine. The 5 frames of lag is quite noticeable when I have the webcam run in real time. Similarly, even if I slow it down so that it is only updating the image once every few seconds it still take 5 read()s before the image on screen matches what was happening during the first call to read(). In other words, every read() call is exactly 5 frames behind real time, regardless of what FPS I am reading the frames at.

Comment: so what you are saying is that 4 out of every 5 frames have EXACTLY the same image?

Comment: No, I'm sorry to not be clear. I mean that I call read() once and the result that I get from that read is real time from 5 read() calls ago. So, say I start out by reading from the webcam and I don't have my hand in the frame. If I then put my hand in the frame and read() while it's there, it won't appear on the screen until 4 more reads() later. The 4 reads that I do before it updates to show my hand will *not* be the same frame, they will show the image without my hand because they are also 5 behind. This is regardless of how quickly the reads occur. It's some sort of buffering issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default buffer is set to 4.0 instead of 1.0.

To Fix it:

```
cap.set(38,1)
```

reference: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga41c5cfa7859ae542b71b1d33bbd4d2b4

[image: you can see on picture parameter nr 38.]

Comment: Much better answer! Marking as accepted

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was something to do with the way that my hardware was buffering the frames. I never quite got to the bottom of it but the solution I found was very simple paralellization. I modified my code to open up a thread and constantly update a variable holding the current frame. Then, when I need the current frame I just ask for whatever that variable is at the moment.

Note that this *is* still 5 read() calls behind because of the ever-present buffering, however because I am doing read() calls continuously and it's all on its own thread, it is very up to date. This is because I can call many read() calls per second. The image I get is not noticeably behind real-time at all.

The Python class I made to do this is below. It is *not* very nice code but it works. To do this properly, I would (and will) add graceful ways to exit the infinite loop. It will work for me though and it has improved the speed of my image detection code by well over 100 fold, which is extremely awesome and exciting for me :)

```
class webcamImageGetter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.currentFrame = None
        self.CAMERA_WIDTH = #webcam width
        self.CAMERA_HEIGHT = #webcam height
        self.CAMERA_NUM = 0

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Put in correct capture number here
        #OpenCV by default gets a half resolution image so we manually set the correct resolution
        self.capture.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,self.CAMERA_WIDTH)
        self.capture.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,self.CAMERA_HEIGHT)

    #Starts updating the images in a thread
    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.updateFrame, args=()).start()

    #Continually updates the frame
    def updateFrame(self):
        while(True):
            ret, self.currentFrame = self.capture.read()

            while (self.currentFrame == None): #Continually grab frames until we get a good one
                ret, frame = self.capture.read()

    def getFrame(self):
        return self.currentFrame
```

To use this, you initialize it then called start on the instance. This will make it so when you later called getFrame(), it will have the most up to date frame from the webcam. Woohoo!

Comment: I don't know how to use this code. I copy-pasted it into a different file I called "lastFrame.py". In my main file I wanted to write "from lastFrame import init", "from lastFrame import start", and so on with all the defined functions, but it didn't let me do that.

Comment: 'from lastFrame import webcamImageGetter' is what you want, then do something like 'imageGetter = webcamImageGetter()' then 'imageGetter.start()'. After that, you can call 'imageGetter.getFrame()' to get new frames.